# What did I do wrong when building receiver with pyserial?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, xbee

I am using XBee modem to make mutual remote communication system.

Initially I tried using Arduino, however, I figured out that using two single board computer with python would be much more convenient. I am using pyserial right now.

This is the code which I made. It is really simple, and I don't see there would be something cause error.

Transmitter

```
import serial
import time
Xserial=serial.Serial('COM4',9600)

for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    Xserial.write(b"Test2")
    time.sleep(3)
Xserial.close()
```

Receiver

```
import serial
import time
XSerial=serial.Serial('COM10',9600)
while (True):
    line=XSerial.read(1)
    print(line)
XSerial.close()
```

I think transmitter is working, however, receiver does not seem to receive what I send.

I am sure that it was working yesterday, but it is not working today. I checked XCTU and the connection is fine. I can communicate with each other by XCTU.

Comment: They definitely on the right COM ports?

Comment: Yes. It works properly with XCTU.

Comment: What does the receiving end show?  It looks like you're only reading a single character at a time (`read(1)`).

Comment: And if you have simple requirements, perhaps using MicroPython on an XBee3 module would be the way to go.  No need for an additional microprocessor and it eliminates the serial communication.